# Difference between character sets in Python and re2c regular expressions

Tags: python, regex

Character sets in regular expressions are specified using []. Character sets match any one of the enclosed characters. For example, [abc] will match one of 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

I realize there are potentially differences between character sets in [Python](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) and [re2c](http://re2c.org/manual.html) regular expressions. I know what is the same in both:

- Both accept ranges, for example [a-z] matches all lowercase letters
- Both accept inverse sets using [^...] notation
- Both accept common alphanumeric and some other characters (spaces, etc.)

But I'm concerned about these possibly being different:

- Characters that need to be escaped inside of the character set
- Where to place a literal '-' or '^' inside the character set if I want to match that character and not specify an inverse set or a range

Can you explain the difference between Python and re2c character sets?

Comment: Never heard of or used re2c, but the examples look like your average PCRE - and Python `re` is PCRE too, so there shouldn't be significant differences (at most subtle semantic differences in the more advanced features like lookaround).

Comment: re2c is a significantly stripped down version of PCRE/Python. It uses DFAs to check multiple regular expressons for matches all at once. In short, if I have 'm' regular expressions of length O(n) characters then re2c determines which one matches in O(n), as opposed to O(m*n) which PCRE and Python can do at best. re2c has less power, so less characters mean something special implying that character sets could be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the re2c manual link that you provided, it appears that re2c uses the same syntax, just a subset of that syntax.

To address your specific questions about regex syntax

> Characters that need to be escaped inside of the character set.

What characters are you referring to specifically?

> Where to place a literal `-` or `^` inside the character set...

For `^`, anywhere but the beginning should do, and for `-`, anywhere but in the middle should do.

```
>>> import re
>>> match_literal_hyphen = "[ab-]"
>>> re.findall(match_literal_hyphen, "abc - def")
['a', 'b', '-']
>>> match_literal_caret = "[a^b]"
>>> re.findall(match_literal_caret, "abc ^ def")
['a', 'b', '^']
```

Comment: I'm referring to characters .$*+?{}() which have special meaning in Python, I'm assuming that a backslash and [] will need escaping, i.e. I would use [\\[\\]\\\] to match any of '[', ']', '\'

Answer (score 0):

I would escape anything that causes confusion -

`/[][]/` matches ']' or '['
`/[[]]/` matches '[]'
`/[]]]/` matches ']]'
`/[[[]/` matches '['
`/[]/` is an umatched '[' error

Comment: So you're suggesting to do [\\[\\]]? I think that works in both Python and re2c, but does that mean those are the only two characters that need to be escaped?